# Capitalize new construction introduced in mathematical proof

Tags: nouns, capitalization, mathematics

Let's say that I am trying to prove a mathematical theorem. As part of that proof, I may want to introduce a construction that I will use repeatedly throughout the proof (and potentially combine many instantiations of the same construct). To that end, let's say that I name the construct Named Thing. I may say something like the following:

> We will create a *Named Thing*. A Named Thing has the following structure etc.

Should Named Thing be capitalized in both cases here? It's used somewhat like a proper noun here, although it's referring to a *class* of objects, as opposed to referring to a single specific object from this class.

Furthermore, let's now consider the following sentence:

> We construct named things for each of the five cases.

Here I believe it should be lower case, as its usage is (I believe) as a common noun. Is that correct?

Comment: In either cases using upper case sounds a little odd. If the name is new which  will repeat, you can give a legend or a reference like (XYZ referred to as X else in this...).

Comment: Thanks both, this is also my intuition actually. But a coauthor is using an alternative capitalization scheme (the one in the post), and I realized that I don't know how to justify my approach.

Comment: 'Coauthor' hints at writing an academic paper. While 'how to introduce a new term' is essentially a matter of opinion (and opinions often differ), institutions usually make their preferences known in their in-house style guide (often different from nearby rivals').